# How to create date filter with range with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My boss wants me to create filter date by range but I cannot use `ajax`, and now I am stuck with the filter date showing; but when I choose the date it does not change my query. Is there anythings wrong with my code or is there any solution that I can use except using `ajax`?

**Controller**

```
public function daterange(Request $request)
{
    $daterange =
    $dateRange = DB::table('order_items')
    ->whereBetween('created_at', array(
        (Carbon::parse($request->input('datepicker_from'))->format('Y-m-d')),
        (Carbon::parse($request->input('datepicker_to'))->format('Y-m-d'))
        )
       )
      ->get();
    return view('profiles.dateRange', ['date_range' => $dateRange]);
}
```

This is my view blade
**table.blade.php**(views/order_items)
**Blade**

```
@section('styles')
    @include('layouts.datatables_css')
@endsection
<tbody><tr>
            <td>Minimum date:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="datepicker_from" name="datepicker_from"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Maximum date:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="datepicker_to" name="datepicker_to"></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- <input type="button" name="search" id="search" value="Search" class="btn btn-info" /> -->
    </tbody></table>
<div class="table-responsive">
    {!! $dataTable->table(['width' => '100%'], true) !!}
</div>

@section('scripts')
    @include('layouts.datatables_js')
    {!! $dataTable->scripts() !!}

    <script>
        $('#dataTableBuilder thead').append('<tr class="column-search"></tr>');
        $('#dataTableBuilder thead th').each(function() {
            var title = $(this).text();
            if(title === 'Action') {
                $('.column-search').append('<td></td>');
            } else {
                $('.column-search').append('<td><input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" /></td>');
            }
        });

        var table = $('#dataTableBuilder').DataTable();

        var idx = 0;
        table.columns().every(function() {
            var that = this;

            $('input', $('.column-search td').get(idx)).on('keyup change', function() {
                if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                    that
                        .search(this.value)
                        .draw();
                }
            });
            idx++;
            $("#datepicker_from").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
            // startDate: '01-10-2017',
        onselect: function (dateText) {
            $("#datepicker_to").datepicker('option', 'minDate', dateText);
        }
        });
        $("#datepicker_to").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
            // endDate: '01-11-2017',
        });
        });

        $("#datepicker_from").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
            // startDate: '01-10-2017',
        onselect: function (dateText) {
            $("#datepicker_to").datepicker('option', 'minDate', dateText);
        }
        });
        $("#datepicker_to").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
            // endDate: '01-11-2017',
        });
    </script>[enter image description here][2]
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

use daterangepicker.js to pick the dates.

```
$startTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", substr($request->input('datepicker_from'), 0, 10));
$endTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", substr($request->input('datepicker_to'), 0, 10));
```

Query:

```
OrderItems::whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'),[$startTime, $endTime])->get();
```